# Adding some input nodes in the middle of a DNN

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, bioinformatics

In this bioinformatics paper: [paper link](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/30/12/i121/387635/Deep-learning-of-the-tissue-regulated-splicing) is used the following DNN (Deep Neural Network):
[image: DNN]
where some input nodes were added (concatenated) to the first hidden layer.

Does anybody know the name of this technique? I would like to know more but I can not find any information about it.